# How to convert currency in Google Docs Spreadsheet cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, currency

Okay I have a cell with Russian Roubles and want to convert them into US Dollars. What is the formula? I tried to find some keywords with `=something` (currency,finance,convert,dollar,double,ruble and much more) but found nothing.

Comment: Why not simply multiply it by the exchange rate?  (ie =a1*.029)

Comment: Perhaps it was lost in translation, but your question asks for a formula, instead of a function to retrieve a dynamically updated coversion ratio.  Note the following probably has what you are looking for:  http://superuser.com/questions/286192/formula-for-updated-currency-exchange-rates-in-excel-or-other-spreadsheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain function available in Google Spreadsheets to interact with other Google services such as Finance.
To get the realtime exchange rate between currencies and set up conversion you could follow these steps:

- Get the exchange rate between currencies in a cell, or use it directly in a formula using the function: `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")`. The format is `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:<from-currency><to-currency>")`
- Use it in a formula: `=C4*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")`